# Clarity with the output of this code

Tags: java, file-io

```
 FileInputStream filepath= new FileInputStream(path+ "/" + file);
 BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(filepath));
 StringBuffer stringbuffer= new StringBuffer();
 String strLine;
 //Assuming there is some file with some data in it
 while((strLine = br.readLine())!=null)
 {
 stringbuffer.append(strLine);
 stringbuffer.append("\f");
 }
```

Will the value of strLine at the end be null or The data obtained by readline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can only be null, because that is the only condition when the loop will stop.

Comment: So how to make sure that we get the data in the file in strLine?

Comment: strLine= stringbuffer.toString();
This will copy the data to the string right?

Comment: ...if you like, yes?  I'd use a different variable for the lines and the final result.

Answer (score 1):

`strLine` value  will be null because this condition is what breaks the while loop.